# Complex Counting of dataframe with factors

Tags: r, shiny

I have this table.

```
'data.frame':   5303 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ Metric.ID          : num  7156 7220 7220 7220 7220 ...
 $ Metric.Name        : Factor w/ 99 levels "Avoid accessing data by using the position and length",..: 51 59 59 
 $ Technical.Criterion: Factor w/ 25 levels "Architecture - Multi-Layers and Data Access",..: 4 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 ...
 $ RT.Snapshot.name   : Factor w/ 1 level "2017_RT12": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Violation.status   : Factor w/ 2 levels "Added","Deleted": 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Critical.Y.N       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Grouping           : Factor w/ 29 levels "281","Bes",..: 27 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 ...
 $ Object.type        : Factor w/ 11 levels "Cobol Program",..: 8 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
 $ Object.name        : Factor w/ 3771 levels "[S:\\SOURCES\\",..: 3771 3770 3769 3768 3767 3
```

I want to have a statistic output like this:
For every Technical.Criterion a row with the sum of all rows of Critical.Y.N = 0 and 1

[image]

So I have to combine the rows of my database to a new matrix. Using Values of the factor sums ...

But I have no idea how to start...? Any hints?

Thanks

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput` and expected output

Comment: Please take a look to my "sample of the final table". It shows the combination of items to calculate the sum.

Comment: I need 25 rows for all "Technical Criterion". There are 11 "Object.Type" for the colomns under each "Violation.status". So my first sum (17) is the result of: Count all Lines of my data frame where the "Technical Criterion" is the first one ("Architecture - Multi-Layers..."), the "violation.status" is the first one ("added") and the "Object Type" is the first one ("Cobol Program"). At the end all 5303 rows have to benn calculated in that table.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're asking for a cross-tabulation. Because you did not provide a reproducible sample, I've used mine:

```
xtabs(~ Sub.Category + Category, retail)
```

Produce this:
[image]

And if you want the value to be say, based on Sales, instead of the count, then you can modify the code to:

```
xtabs(Sales ~ Sub.Category + Category, retail)
```

And you will get the following output:
[image]

**EDIT based on extra information in the OP's comment**
If you want to have your tables also share a common title and want to change the name of that title, you can use a combination of `names()` and `dimnames()`. An `xtab` is a cross-tabulation table and if you call `dimnames()` on it it returns a list of length 2, first one corresponding to the row and second to the column.

```
dimnames(xtab(dat))
$Technical.Criterion
[1] "TechnicalCrit1" "TechnicalCrit2" "TechnicalCrit3"

$`Object.type`
[1] "Object.type1" "Object.type2" "Object.type3"
```

So given a data frame, `b`:

```
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ Metric.ID          : int  101 102 103
 $ Metric.Name        : Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
 $ Technical.Criterion: Factor w/ 3 levels "TechnicalCrit1",..: 1 2 3
 $ RT.Snapshot.name   : Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
 $ Violation.status   : Factor w/ 2 levels "Added","Deleted": 1 2 1
 $ Critical.Y.N       : num  1 0 1
 $ Grouping           : Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
 $ Object.type        : Factor w/ 3 levels "Object.type1",..: 1 2 3
 $ Object.name        : Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
```

We can use `xtab` and then change the "common" header right at the top of our table. Since I don't know how many levels are in `b$Violation.status`, I would use a generic for loop:

```
for(i in 1:length(unique(b$Violation.status))){
  tab[[i]] <- xtabs(Critical.Y.N ~ Technical.Criterion + Object.type, b)
  names(dimnames(tab[[i]]))[2] <- paste("Violation.status", i)
}
```

This produces:

```
                   Violation.status 1
Technical.Criterion Object.type1 Object.type2 Object.type3
     TechnicalCrit1            1            0            0
     TechnicalCrit2            0            0            0
     TechnicalCrit3            0            0            1
```

Which I can now use in my shiny app.

Comment: The problem is that I have a database with factors. I need 25 rows for all "Technical Criterion". There are 11 "Object.Type" for the colomns under each "Violation.status". So my first sum (17) is the result of: Count all Lines of my data frame where the "Technical Criterion" is the first one ("Architecture - Multi-Layers..."), the "violation.status" is the first one ("added") and the "Object Type" is the first one ("Cobol Program"). At the end all 5303 rows have to benn calculated in that table.

Comment: @Talcom expanded my answer to help you with it.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I'm a newbie an eveything is new for me. I get an error "object 'tab' not found". There are only 2 levels in Violation.status